# Ingresar ceros a la izquierda en (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

estoy insertando en mi base de datos la placa de los vehiculos, utilizando conca para unir las letras de las placas con el rango numerico.

este es el codigo que tengo:

```
$letras = $_POST['letras'];
$inicial = $_POST['inicial'];
$final = $_POST['final'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

    for ($i = $inicial; $i <= $final; $i++)
    {           
        $query = "INSERT INTO placas (placa, usuario) VALUES (concat('$letras', '$i'), '$usuario')"; 

        $inicial = "$inicial" + "001";
}
```

el codigo me funciona y me guarda la placa pero asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que las placas me salgan con los tres numeros.. ejemplo> AAA001, AAA002, etc pero no me coge los ceros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que concatenas directamente el valor de `$i` a tu campo `placa` en `(concat('$letras', '$i')`

Lo que necesitas es hacer un padding que tenga los ceros necesarios antes de concatenarlo:

```php
$numConCeros= sprintf("%03d", $i); // Agregamos los leading zeros
$query = "INSERT INTO placas (placa, usuario) VALUES (concat('$letras', '$numConCeros'), '$usuario')";
```

---

Por cierto si ese código representa in serio riezgo de inyeccion SQL

Comment: excelente!! muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se puede verificar si $i es menor que 10 o está entre 10 y 99, y así concatenar con los ceros:

```
for ($i = $inicial; $i <= $final; $i++)
{
        $ceros = "";
        if($i < 10){
            $ceros = "00";
        } else if ($i >= 10 AND $i <= 99) {
            $ceros = "0";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO placas (placa, usuario) VALUES (concat('$letras','$ceros','$i'), '$usuario')"; 

}
```

Comment: Tambien probe el tuyo amigo, pero si insertaba mas de 100 placas, la placa: AAA100 no la inserta y saca error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi
Formateando el texto donde le decimos que pinte `3d` osea 3 enteros o complete con 0 en caso de que se pase 1 u 2

```
$ti = sprintf("%03d", $i);
```

Y ahora haces un concat de `$ti` en vez de $i.